# Trying to create a directory if it doesn't exist

Tags: c, file-system

I am trying to create a directory, but I have to check whether `/usr` is present initially, later `/usr/local` is present and so on, is this an elegant way of writing it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="/usr/local/mnt/";
  char path[40] = {0};
  char temp[40] = {0};
  char *slash = "/";
  char *pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,"/");
  printf (" First one %s\n",pch);
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s%s%s", temp, slash, pch);
    strncpy(temp, path, 40);
    if (stat(path, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
        printf("Directory path already exists\n");
    }
    else{
          if(mkdir(path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO) != 0){
            printf("directory creation error");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    pch = strtok (NULL, "/");

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile. `sb` is not declared, and the header files are missing. To avoid the closing votes, please update the code to compile cleanly.